# Why do we have to write -1 after .count in this Swift code?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the following Swift code:

```swift
self.numbers[2] = Int.random(in: 0...self.symbols.count-1)
```

Why do we have to write  `-1`?

I don't understand the code.

Comment: You shouldn't, but the premise is because in an array the the `index` starts at `0` so a if you only have 1 item (`count == 1`) in an array, you find it with `numbers[0]` if you were to put `1` as the index it would say `index out of range`. `numbers[1]` would imply that there are at least 2 items in an array. But, going back to why you shouldn't, if your array has `isEmpty` you would get an error because you would tell that line of code `0...-1` and the `upperbound` would be less than the `lowerbound`

Comment: `Count` is a total positions of something.
But when we are dealing with `Index` we actually need the total index positions which means until (...count-1 which is same as <=count-1) OR we can stop on count ( <count ) which your last position will be count-1

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `A...B`, that range includes `B` in it. See [`...(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable/2949800) docs. So if you say -

```
Int.random(in: 0...self.symbols.count-1)
```

It means range starts at `0` and ends at `symbols.count-1` including both.

Say an array has `2` elements, it's `count` is `2`, but valid indices are `0`, `1` (`2` is not a valid index), so you are just making sure that it is restricted to valid index values.

Other way to write the same would be - `A..<B`, in this range, `B` is not included. See [`..<(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable/2949700) docs. Following is same as above.

```
Int.random(in: 0..<self.symbols.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [ClosedRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange) here. It is a range which includes both start and end value of the range. You can also used simple [Range](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range), which is open so to say. It only includes start value and not the final value.

Lets take an example.

```
let a = 1 ... 10 // includes all values from 1 to 10
let b = 1 ..< 10 // includes values from 1 to 9
```

So, basically what you are writing here,

```
self.numbers[2] = Int.random(in: 0 ... self.symbols.count - 1)
```

is equivalent to open range using,

```
self.numbers[2] = Int.random(in: 0 ..< self.symbols.count)
```

such that you dont need to add `-1` to it.

`Int.random` can take both ClosedRange and Range, [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2995648-random)  and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2995646-random).

Answer (score 0):

Here are your code:

```
self.numbers[2] = Int.random(in: 0...self.symbols.count-1)
```

It says: your third item in `numbers` array will be assigned by the random item of `symbols` array

But how to get the random item of `symbols` array? You'll get it by its index.

The indexes of an array starting from 0, so, for the last element of array, its index will be the array length - 1, for example, with `[1,2,3]`, the last element's index will be 2.

Here, you used Closed Range, it will include the last element, so if you don't minus count by one, the last index will be 3 (because array.count will return the length of the array), which is produce `out of index` error